# Unexpected output when running function to find max product in array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This function is supposed to comb through an array and find the largest product of any two adjacent indices (I.E the answer to [4,5,2,1] would be 20.) Most of my tests seem to work, but when **inputArray = [-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]** , my output is 0. Why?

```
function largestProduct(inputArray) {
  let arr = inputArray;
  let answer = 0;
  let ansArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1;i++){
    let product = arr[i] * arr[i+1];
    ansArr.push(product);
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < ansArr.length; i++){
    if(ansArr[i] > answer){
      answer = ansArr[i];
    }
  }
  return answer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the products are less than 0. You should init answer with [`-Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity), which will always be less than your product.

```js
function largestProduct(inputArray) {
  let arr = inputArray;
  let answer = -Infinity;
  let ansArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    let product = arr[i] * arr[i + 1];
    ansArr.push(product);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < ansArr.length; i++) {
    if (ansArr[i] > answer) {
      answer = ansArr[i];
    }
  }
  return answer
}

console.log(largestProduct([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]));
```

You can also refactor your code to a single loop:

```js
function largestProduct(arr) {
  let answer = -Infinity;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    const product = arr[i] * arr[i + 1];
    answer = answer > product ? answer : product;
  }
  
  return answer
}

console.log(largestProduct([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The case when your all the products are less than 0. You should init answer equal 0 after the first loop, so I was Thinking in this solution

```
function largestProduct(inputArray) {
  let arr = inputArray;
  let ansArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1;i++){
    let product = arr[i] * arr[i+1];
    ansArr.push(product);
  }
  let answer = ansArr.length > 0 ? ansArr[1] : 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < ansArr.length; i++){
    if(ansArr[i] > answer){
      answer = ansArr[i];
    }
  }
  return answer
}
```